# Android: receiving IllegalArgumentException after directly importing SlidingDrawer source code

Tags: android, handle, slidingdrawer

I got an IAE when copying the SlidingDrawer code from Android SDK and importing it into my project.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The handle attribute is required and must refer to a valid child.

This is my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/MySlidingDrawer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="test only"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <com.mytest.view.SlidingDrawer
        android:id="@+id/SlidingDrawer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="250dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:content="@+id/contentLayout"
        android:handle="@+id/slideButton"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:topOffset="100.5dp"
        android:padding="10dip" >

        <Button
            android:id="@id/slideButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="UP" >
        </Button>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@id/contentLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dip" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button01"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:text="Button01" >
            </Button>
        </LinearLayout>
    </com.mytest.view.SlidingDrawer>

</RelativeLayout>
```

this is my attrs:

```
  <declare-styleable name="SlidingDrawer"> 
        <attr name = "orientation"  format="integer"/>
        <attr name = "bottomOffset" format = "dimension"/>
        <attr name = "topOffset" format = "dimension"/>
        <attr name = "allowSingleTap" format = "boolean"/>
        <attr name = "animateOnClick" format = "boolean"/>
        <attr name = "handle" format = "reference"/>
        <attr name = "content" format = "reference"/>
    </declare-styleable>
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this is an issue so it's not your problem.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3162

i think that's why the sliding drawer is deprecated on API level 17.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

On your Button, try changing `android:id="@id/slideButton"` to `android:id="@+id/slideButton"`

<strike>The View that acts as the handle for your sliding drawer needs to have android:id="@id/handle" for SlidingDrawer to work</strike>

Comment: I have android:handle="@+id/slideButton" which refers to the button below, doesn't it do the work?

Answer (score 0):

check this Link. I think you have to declare your own name space to refer the Handler 
http://chrisharrington1.wordpress.com/2012/02/06/android-modifying-the-slidingdrawer-widget-to-use-a-max-height/

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you imported the class as a custom view yet you still use :

```
android:content="@+id/contentLayout"
android:handle="@+id/slideButton"
```

Use this instead:

```
app:content="@+id/contentLayout"
app:handle="@+id/slideButton"
```